# Zend Translate doesn't find language

Tags: zend-framework, internationalization, zend-translate

I've got a Zend Translate Issue. I have configure the zend translate in the bootstrap like below

```
public function _initTranslate() {
    $locale = new Zend_Locale();
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);

    $translate = new Zend_Translate(array(
                'adapter' => 'ini'
                    )
    );

    $translate->addTranslation(
            array(
                'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/languages/pt.ini',
                'locale' => 'pt'
            )
    );
    $translate->addTranslation(
            array(
                'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/languages/en.ini',
                'locale' => 'en'
            )
    );

    $translate->setLocale($locale);
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
}
```

I've added the languages and in my views I used translate helper but it shows me the following erros

```
Notice: The language 'en' has to be added before it can be used. 
in C:\xampp\ZendFramework-1.11.10\library\Zend\Translate\Adapter.php 
on line 443
Notice: No translation for the language 'en' available. 
in C:\xampp\ZendFramework-1.11.10\library\Zend\Translate\Adapter.php 
on line 456
```

I've followed zendframework reference guide. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to add this lines: $Options = array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME); new Zend_Translate('ini', APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/languages/', LOCALE_LANGUAGE, $Options); where LOCALE_LANGUAGE has to be set by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved ths issue with the code below:

```
public function _initTranslate() {
    $this->bootstrap('locale');
    if($this->hasResource('locale')){
        $locale = $this->getResource('locale');
    }

    $translate = new Zend_Translate(array(
                'adapter' => 'ini',
                'disableNotices' => true,
                )
    );

    $translate->getAdapter()->addTranslation(
            array(
                'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/languages/pt.ini',
                'locale' => 'pt'
            )
    );
    $translate->getAdapter()->addTranslation(
            array(
                'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/languages/en.ini',
                'locale' => 'en'
            )
    );
    if($translate->getAdapter()->isAvailable($locale->getLanguage())){
        $translate->getAdapter()->setLocale($locale->getLanguage());
    }else{
        $translate->getAdapter()->setLocale('en');
    }
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
}
```

And I coded a plugin to change language at runtime by just passing a GET variable Ex.: &lang=en

```
class Sistema_Plugin_Translate extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

        $translate = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');
        $locale = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale');
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('language');

        //verifica se existe GET e valida
        if ($request->isGet()) {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_Alpha();
            $param = $filter->filter($request->getParam('lang'));
            if (!empty($param) && $locale->isLocale($param) && $translate->getAdapter()->isAvailable($param)) {
                $translate->getAdapter()->setLocale($param);
                $session->language = $param;
            }
        }

        //verifica se o idioma do browser está disponivel se não coloca um idioma padrão
        if (!$translate->getAdapter()->isAvailable($locale->getLanguage())) {
            //linguagem não disponivel,seta idioma en
            $translate->getAdapter()->setLocale('en');
        }

        //verifica se há sessão com idioma definido
        if (isset($session->language)) {
            if ($translate->getAdapter()->isAvailable($session->language)) {
                $translate->getAdapter()->setLocale($session->language);

            }
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try passing a language to `Zend_Locale`?

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_US');
```

Additionally, I found a work around:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);

$translate = new Zend_Translate(
    'ini',
    $yourPath,
    null,
    array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY));

// setting the right locale
if ($translate->isAvailable($locale->getLanguage())) {
    $translate->setLocale($locale);
} else {
    $translate->setLocale('en_US');
}
```

See http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6612 for more details. Note: this is a bug for 1.8, I see you're using 1.10 but the work-around might still work.

This is also a good thread: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/how-handle-Locale-td659923.html

Also, `Zend_Translate` offers an option to disable notices specifically for that class. If the content *is* being translated, then this (according to Zend) is not an "*error*" and notices should be disabled.

```
// as a fourth parameter to Zend_Translate pass it:
array('disableNotices' => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try Poedit for Localization ..BTW its a great tool..here's the step by step way

IN your bootstrap...

```
    protected function _initLanguage() {

            // initialising translator
            $translator = new Zend_Translate(
                            array(
                                'adapter' => 'gettext',
                                'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/languages/en/default.mo',
                                'locale' => 'en'
                            )
            );

            Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translator);

            $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
            $frontController->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_Translate());
        }
```

/**********End of code for bootstrap******/
    /*Plugin file** save in your plugins directory*/

```
        class Application_Plugin_Translate extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
        {
    /**
     * Translation object
     *
     * @var Zend_Translate_Adapter
     */
    protected $_translator;

    /**
     * Constructor for manually handling
     *
     * @param Zend_Translate|Zend_Translate_Adapter $translate Instance of Zend_Translate
     */
    public function __construct($translate = null)
    {
        if ($translate !== null) {
            $this->setTranslator($translate);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Translate a message
     * You can give multiple params or an array of params.
     * If you want to output another locale just set it as last single parameter
     * Example 1: translate('%1\$s + %2\$s', $value1, $value2, $locale);
     * Example 2: translate('%1\$s + %2\$s', array($value1, $value2), $locale);
     *
     * @param  string $messageid Id of the message to be translated
     * @return string|Zend_View_Helper_Translate Translated message
     */
    public function translate($messageid = null)
    {
        if ($messageid === null) {
            return $this;
        }

        $translate = $this->getTranslator();
        $options   = func_get_args();

        array_shift($options);
        $count  = count($options);
        $locale = null;
        if ($count > 0) {
            if (Zend_Locale::isLocale($options[($count - 1)], null, false) !== false) {
                $locale = array_pop($options);
            }
        }

        if ((count($options) === 1) and (is_array($options[0]) === true)) {
            $options = $options[0];
        }

        if ($translate !== null) {
            $messageid = $translate->translate($messageid, $locale);
        }

        if (count($options) === 0) {
            return $messageid;
        }

        return vsprintf($messageid, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Sets a translation Adapter for translation
     *
     * @param  Zend_Translate|Zend_Translate_Adapter $translate Instance of Zend_Translate
     * @throws Zend_View_Exception When no or a false instance was set
     * @return Zend_View_Helper_Translate
     */
    public function setTranslator($translate)
    {
        if ($translate instanceof Zend_Translate_Adapter) {
            $this->_translator = $translate;
        } else if ($translate instanceof Zend_Translate) {
            $this->_translator = $translate->getAdapter();
        } else {
            require_once 'Zend/View/Exception.php';
            $e = new Zend_View_Exception('You must set an instance of Zend_Translate or Zend_Translate_Adapter');
            $e->setView($this->view);
            throw $e;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve translation object
     *
     * @return Zend_Translate_Adapter|null
     */
    public function getTranslator()
    {
        if ($this->_translator === null) {
            require_once 'Zend/Registry.php';
            if (Zend_Registry::isRegistered('Zend_Translate')) {
                $this->setTranslator(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate'));
            }
        }

        return $this->_translator;
    }

    /**
     * Set's an new locale for all further translations
     *
     * @param  string|Zend_Locale $locale New locale to set
     * @throws Zend_View_Exception When no Zend_Translate instance was set
     * @return Zend_View_Helper_Translate
     */
    public function setLocale($locale = null)
    {
        $translate = $this->getTranslator();
        if ($translate === null) {
            require_once 'Zend/View/Exception.php';
            $e = new Zend_View_Exception('You must set an instance of Zend_Translate or Zend_Translate_Adapter');
            $e->setView($this->view);
            throw $e;
        }

        $translate->setLocale($locale);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the set locale for translations
     *
     * @throws Zend_View_Exception When no Zend_Translate instance was set
     * @return string|Zend_Locale
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
        $translate = $this->getTranslator();
        if ($translate === null) {
            require_once 'Zend/View/Exception.php';
            $e = new Zend_View_Exception('You must set an instance of Zend_Translate or Zend_Translate_Adapter');
            $e->setView($this->view);
            throw $e;
        }

        return $translate->getLocale();
    }

    public function direct($messageid = null)
    {
        return $this->translate($messageid);
    }
}
```

/************A library file for translation***************/

```
<?php

class Application_Locale {  



protected $_locale = 'en'; //default language 
function __construct($locale = null) {     

    $session->locale = $this->_locale; //Change this accordingly to your suit ir when you change the lang drop down box..change this..etc
}

/* get locale */

public function getLocale() {
    return $this->_locale;
}
public static function translate($string){ //a custom function for translation

    $translate = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');
    return $translate->translate($string);

    }

}
```

And finally in your application you can call Application_Locale::translate('your string') for translation
And most importanty read this for setting up poedit for your application
http://techie.ayyappadas.com/how-do-use-poeditor

Answer (score 0):

As i expressed in my app, Following notice happen when you pass incomplete array to Zend_Translate

> Notice: The language 'en' has to be added before it can be used.

You should add en with some parameter in it like :

```
    $english = array(
        'message1' => 'message1',
        'message2' => 'message2',
        'message3' => 'message3');

    $translate = new Zend_Translate(
        array(
            'adapter' => 'array',
            'content' => $english,
            'locale'  => 'en'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into `Project_dir/resources/languages` is there an `en` folder available? If not please look in available language folder and create `Zend_Validate.php` file there for English validation error messages.